# Join status by dates in bigquery

Tags: sql, date, join, google-bigquery, between

I have Table A

| SnapshotDat | Invoice ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-12 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-13 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-14 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-15 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-16 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-17 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-18 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-19 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-20 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-21 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-22 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-23 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-24 | 1111 |
| 2022-09-25 | 1111 |

Table B

| Date | Invoice ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 | 1111 | draft |
| 2022-09-15 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-20 | 1111 | pending |
| 2022-09-24 | 1111 | paid |

And I want to establish a join by Invoice ID and Dates, to have this table result

| SnapshotDat | Invoice ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 | 1111 | draft |
| 2022-09-12 | 1111 | draft |
| 2022-09-13 | 1111 | draft |
| 2022-09-14 | 1111 | draft |
| 2022-09-15 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-16 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-17 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-18 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-19 | 1111 | outstanding |
| 2022-09-20 | 1111 | pending |
| 2022-09-21 | 1111 | pending |
| 2022-09-22 | 1111 | pending |
| 2022-09-23 | 1111 | pending |
| 2022-09-24 | 1111 | paid |
| 2022-09-25 | 1111 | paid |

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT a.SnapshotDate, a.invoiceid, b.status 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.invoiceid = b.invoiceid 
           AND a.SnapshotDate<=b.Date
```

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: select 
a.SnapshotDate,
a.invoiceid,
b.status
from a
left join b
on a.invoiceid=b.invoiceid and a.SnapshotDate<=b.Date

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach (assuming your dates related columns are actually of `date` data type

```
select a.*, status
from TableA as a
join (
  select *, 
    ifnull(-1 + lead(date) over(partition by invoiceId order by date), current_date()) lastDate
  from TableB
) as b
on a.invoiceId = b.invoiceId
and snapshotDate between date and lastDate
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]